# Time Update Application

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a digital clock in android.

I looked into the Time and Date classes.

However I cannot find any API that is tells me how to obtain when a minute has passed?
For e.g. when working with locationManagers,

```
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
```

is called when new location is available.

Similarly I am looking for something that is called when time changes, where time is in format hh:mm or hh:mm:ss.

Comment: `Thread.wait(1000);` ? waits 1 second, doesn't it? (never did android stuff, just java)

Comment: never did threading! :(

Comment: This will make the particular thread wait right? But U want to trigger something when 1s is elapsed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net) for this code, but you should be using it anyway for anything involving time calculations in Java.

```
public DateTime date = new DateTime();
public void updateClock {
if (Seconds.secondsBetween(new DateTime(), date).getValue() != 1) { 
    return;
}
date = new DateTime();
// do your thing
}
```

Comment: I was using the locationChanged as an example.

Comment: I need an API like this for clock.

Comment: The construct still applies, no matter what your method is.

Comment: for location I need the main_activity to implement location manager.
Does the same also apply for this?
When do I call updateClock?

Comment: Where I've put "// do your thing"?